# How do i get Quality Printout Settings

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, image-quality, color-spaces

How can I get a sharp and quality print with the right color settings?

I use a windows version of Photoshop CS6.

I get my colors looking nice on the laptop but after print, the colors either appear dull or not exactly the colors I saw when designing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do some research on the differences between RGB and CMYK colors.  Your screen is in RGB and your printed design is (usually) CMYK.  I say "usually" because some printers use PMS, which allows for more vivid colors than CMYK, but neither will look as vivid as your RGB design does on-screen.

If you know that you are designing for print, configure Photoshop accordingly, when creating a new document:

[image: settings]

To convert an existing document's color mode, use the option pictured below.

[image: change color]

Also, if it's not already at 300 dpi, set it to that as well, via the Image Size window (**IMAGE > IMAGE SIZE**).

[image: size]